# Error in forestplot.default: You have provided 2 rows in your mean argument while the labels have 34 rows

Tags: r, r-forestplot, hazard

I am trying to make a forestplot in R.

Sample provided by this site: https://designdatadecisions.wordpress.com/2016/07/02/forest-plot-with-horizontal-bands/

Starting with reading the data in R.

**Formatting so the column labels and columns match**

```
subgps <- c(4,5,8,9,12,13,16,17,20,21,24,25,28,29,32,33)
data$Variable[subgps] <- paste("  ",data$Variable[subgps]) 
np <- ifelse(!is.na(data$Count), paste(data$Count," (",data$Percent,")",sep=""), NA)
tabletext <- cbind(c("Subgroup","\n",data$Variable), 
                    c("No. of Patients (%)","\n",np), 
                    c("4-Yr Cum. Event Rate\n PCI","\n",data$PCI.Group), 
                    c("4-Yr Cum. Event Rate\n Medical Therapy","\n",data$Medical.Therapy.Group), 
                    c("P Value","\n",data$P.Value))
```

So far no error.

After I try to do the second step, an error shows-up.
The second step is as following:

```
library(forestplot)
png(file.path(workdir,"Figures\\Forestplot.png"),width=960, height=640)
forestplot(labeltext=tabletext, graph.pos=3, 
           mean=c(NA,NA,data$Point.Estimate), 
           lower=c(NA,NA,data$Low), upper=c(NA,NA,data$High),
           title="Hazard Ratio",
           xlab="     <---PCI Better---    ---Medical Therapy Better--->",
           hrzl_lines=list("3" = gpar(lwd=1, col="#99999922"), 
                          "7" = gpar(lwd=60, lineend="butt", columns=c(2:6), col="#99999922"),
                          "15" = gpar(lwd=60, lineend="butt", columns=c(2:6), col="#99999922"),
                          "23" = gpar(lwd=60, lineend="butt", columns=c(2:6), col="#99999922"),
                          "31" = gpar(lwd=60, lineend="butt", columns=c(2:6), col="#99999922")),
           txt_gp=fpTxtGp(label=gpar(cex=1.25),
                              ticks=gpar(cex=1.1),
                              xlab=gpar(cex = 1.2),
                              title=gpar(cex = 1.2)),
           col=fpColors(box="black", lines="black", zero = "gray50"),
           zero=1, cex=0.9, lineheight = "auto", boxsize=0.5, colgap=unit(6,"mm"),
           lwd.ci=2, ci.vertices=TRUE, ci.vertices.height = 0.4)
dev.off()
```

Error:

> Error in forestplot.default(labeltext = tabletext, graph.pos = 3, mean
>   = c(NA,  :    You have provided 2 rows in your mean argument while the labels have 34 rows

**What does this even mean? How to solve This?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means what it says. From the documentation for forestplot:

> mean: A vector or a matrix with the averages. You can also provide a 2D/3D matrix that is automatically converted to the lower/upper parameters.

Did you check `data` to make sure you imported it correctly? If you downloaded it from the link on the blog, it's an .xlsx file.

what do you see, for example, when you try `data$Point.Estimate`?

If it's NULL (I suspect it is), then try downloading it with the `openxlsx` package:

```
install.packages("openxlsx")
library(openxlsx)
data <- read.xlsx("ForestPlotData.csv")
# Presuming you downloaded the file correctly from the url, and its
# in your working directory, and titled "ForestPlotData.csv"
```

Comment: Thank you so much! The function shows: "data$Point.Estimate", however it has to be "data$PointEstimate" without the dot. However, when I try to plot the second part now with forestplot, I get this error: "Error in grid.Call.graphics(L_setviewport, vp, TRUE) : 
  invalid 'layout.pos.col' " What does this mean?

Comment: You're welcome. If I successfully helped you debug, please mark this as the answer and upvote it:)

Comment: If you have an additional question, feel free to ask that and we'll try to help you there.

Comment: Note that, generally, you're going to want to actually post your data so we know what the structure is (for when you post your additional question). Try using `dput()` with an object that can reproduce your error.

Comment: What do you mean with dput()? Sorry, if I am asking stupid questions.

Comment: Try running `?dput()` in your console and reading that. Then try `dput(head(mtcars))`.  That's the kind of thing you should post.